# imageView does not display on the preview scence but still displays on the emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1.3

I am trying to create a game like tic tac toe by using the GridLayout. The preview screen could display the background picture for the GridLayout (the board) but could not display the imageView that I inserted in the GridLayout (the red O). There is also an error in the message box that said:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

I have tried to refresh the layout and rebuild the project but still cannot fix the error.

The preview screen compare to the emulator screen where the two images are displayed

[image]

The code for the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="368dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        app:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:rowCount="3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: which version of com.android.support are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and change only GridLayout take.. you can change root layout instand of constraintLayout take any layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="368dp"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set orientation for grid layout

```
<GridLayout
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your  `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="368dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/red" />
    </GridLayout>
```

This showing preview for me. Try this.
Also check dependency library version
    `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'`

Answer (score 0):

In my Android Studio your xml is both showing in preview and emulator. Try to do following.

**1) Add to you build.gradle(Module.app) these dependencies again**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

**2) After successfully importing dependencies, refresh the Android Studio**

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble upon this error. Change android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout to GridLayout only in the XML. I had the same issue and this was the solution.